# An adjective describing the ability to be hidden

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, neologisms

I am currently trying to find a single word which describes the ability of an object to be hidden.

> *A label that may be hidden --> a* hideable / hidable / hidible *label*

Is there any word like that in the English language?

I found *stashable*, but it does not meet the requirement of consistency across all terms in a computer program code.

The programming language uses certain names for attributes like *Visibility="Hidden"* (not *Visibility="Stashed"*) and I want / need to name a generic type after this attribute.

Do you have any suggestions or do I have to invent a new term and use it in my code (most likely, very few people will see it and the English of those who might see it is even worse than mine).

**The word I am looking for must be derived from *to hide* or it will not meet the requirement.**

Comment: What's wrong with _hideable_?

Comment: What's don't you like about **hidable**? It is listed by [MW Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hidable).

Comment: Can you give us some motivation for the word having to be derived from 'hide'? That seems awfully restrictive, almost arbitrary (unless you are writing a pun or poetry, which are frankly very arbitrary). You want a word that can be understood, not one that meets some hidden technical requirements.

Comment: @JJJ Well, that is what I was looking for! Make a new answer or edit your existing one. I was just not able to find this word ;-)
HIDABLE... great!

Comment: @Mitch some object within a computer program code is to be named like that and due to it being connected to different other objects (pre-named by the programming language itself) I want the terms to be consistent (good readability).

Comment: for what it's worth, _hideable_ is slightly more commonly used than _hidable_ in literature [according to Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hidable%2Chideable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chidable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chideable%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Did you not look up 'hideable' in an online dictionary first?

Comment: I did look it up in 2 online dictionaries... Obviously the wrong ones...

Comment: What does 'The programming language used names certain attributes like Visibility="Hidden" ' leave unsaid, except that 'The programming language used' isn't English, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin It was supposed to mean the programming language has built-in names for attributes which I cannot alter. Thanks, I have edited this sentence which wasn't English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Concealable**, according to [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concealable):

> Able to be concealed.

It's also listed by [Webster's 1913 Dictionary](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Concealable).

With the restriction that the word is derived from the verb *to hide*, you could go with **hidable**, according to [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hidable):

> capable of being hidden

Attribution:

"Concealable." Servent - Wiktionary. Accessed June 13, 2018. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concealable.

"Hidable." Merriam-Webster. Accessed June 13, 2018. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hidable.

Comment: Thanks, a very nice word! Unfortunately, it has nothing to do with the verb *to hide*, so it does not meet the requirement. I will update my question in order to prevent people from suggesting words like this. Thank you anyway!

Comment: conceal IS mentioned in etymological searches.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden is the past participle of hide, from the Old English hydan, which means "to hide or conceal," but also "to bury a corpse."

hide (v.1)

Old English hydan (transitive and intransitive) "to hide, conceal; preserve; hide oneself; bury a corpse," from West Germanic *hudjan (source also of Middle Dutch, Middle Low German huden), from suffixed form of PIE *keudh- (source also of Greek keuthein "to hide, conceal"), from root *(s)keu- "**to cover**, conceal."  [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hide?ref=etymonline_crossreference)

Thus I propose to **cover** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cover)

> a. To hide or screen from view or knowledge; conceal. Often used with
>   up:

ps as to restrictions: derivation from HIDE and to be suitable to use in computer language ... my answer my meet the #bluescreenofdeath!